# Mouse-state suddenly broke in my project.

Tags: c#, xna, mouse, monogame

This is the most unusual error ever!

I am using *XNA(Monogame)* and using the following code to get the mouse state:

```
Mousestate ms = Mouse.GetState();
```

Then I could check for *clicks* with the following:

```
if(ms.RightButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
{
}
```

Or check for *scroll* by setting a *previous scroll* variable and compare it to the current one.

All was working well, until I was working on my system today, and I tested it and all mouse interaction stopped working. But keyboard state did work.

I thought it could be because it was not getting called or was not being checked.

So I placed this is my working update method.

```
        if (ms.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            throw new NullRefrenceException(); 
        }
```

I tried Left clicking and nothing happened. Made sure it was not something else by removing the if-statement and sure enough it did throw it.

So after being desperate I created a *Windows Mono-game Proj* and put the same code into the update method.

I left-clicked and the error was thrown sure enough.

I have tried commenting out every line of code which has the word ms/mouseState/Mouse. And only leaving one, but to no avail.

I would create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but my project is very large, and I have declared Mouse-state in over 30 classes.

**I have tried restarting computer, restarting visual-studio, ending all vs/vs-host processes, using a different mouse and lots of code tweaking.**

No errors are thrown, when I try and use break-point near Mouse-state it is not set to null.

If any further information is needed for this question, please say so.

Answer (score 0):

Well. If you initialize Game1.

```
Game1 g1 = new Game1();
```

It will break mouseState.

If a class extends : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game

And uses its methods. If you initialize it again it will break.

Game1 should not be initialized.